# Telling a UITextField to become first responder while embedded in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, first-responder

I have a `UITextField` that is a subview of a `UITableViewCell`.

When my view loads, I want the text field to become first responder. I have a pointer to the text field in the table cell, so to do this I am trying:

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

This returns `NO` all the time, regardless of when it's called, which according to the docs means the text field refused to become first responder... What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

The `textfield` properly responds to being touched. It bring up the keyboard then. It's only when telling it to `becomefirstresponder` programmatically that the problem happens.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Whoops, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896399/becomefirstresponder-on-uitextview-not-working.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It turned out that the text field was nil when I was trying to send it first responder. 
Sending `becomeFirstResponder` later in the life cycle worked.

Comment: @Jaserien
Thanks.I also had the same problem,and solved with your solution.
However i stil can't understand how textfield is getting null in view lifcycle,i haven't released it anywhere,is it ARC which is doing this?
Also what is the best way to solve this kind of situation,should i allocate it again ?

Comment: If something has a strong reference to the textField (i.e. it's added as a subview to another view) it shouldn't be null'd in an ARC project. Check that your textField has a strong reference holding it around.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem with a textfield I had added as a subview to a grouped table view cell - but figured out a solution after some poking around.

Assuming you have given the textfield a tag in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you can do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    myTextField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:kMyTextFieldTag];
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same, and its working first time. But when I and pushing another view and coming back then same code s not working.

Comment: The same problem with me, some problem with new XCode :(

Answer (score 5):

Calling it in the -(void)viewDidLoad would work.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder] 

   //... any other code you need 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not getting the cursor to show up when the `UITextField` was made first responder inside of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  The text field would work just fine and dandy, but it was not showing the blinking cursor inside of the field.  When you would press and hold, the zoom magnify would also not show a cursor.

I got around this odd issue by setting my `becomeFirstResponder` inside of the `didSelectRowAtIndex` method.

Comment: I am having this issue too of the cursor not showing up and have to set the editing property of the uitableview to YES for it to work. Did you manage to resolve your missing cursor issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is your UITableView `editing` property set to `YES`?

Comment: No. The UITextField is a subview that I added manually, not part of the cell by default. I was unaware that the tableview needed to be in editing mode?
Wouldn't this show the delete button?

Comment: My mistake, I read the question too quickly first time around. 

I just tried what you're doing and it works here. At what points in the View's life cycle have you tried sending `becomeFirstResponder` to the text field?